# Who is Darth Sidious?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi, darth-sidious, the-rise-of-skywalker

Is Darth Sidious two people? I heard that Darth Vader killed Darth Sidious, but Darth Sidious comes back in *The Rise of Skywalker*. Also, there is another emperor in *The Last Jedi*, but who is he? Is he also Darth Sidious? If so, how did he survive after Rey chopped him in half in *The Last Jedi*?

Comment: Possible dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/228162/if-palpatine-is-a-clone-then-why-is-his-face-scarred?noredirect=1 - Spoiler. He's a clone

Comment: The "Emperor" who died in The Last Jedi was a different character, Supreme Leader Snoke.

Comment: And Snoke was not technically an Emperor; just the leader of a reclusive and authoritarian military junta/would-be dictatorship in the same vein as Kim Jong-Un.

Answer (score 6):

Darth Sidious is the name used by the Emperor of the Galactic Empire, Sheev Palpatine, in his dealings as a dark lord of the Sith. He was killed during the events of Return of the Jedi by Darth Vader when he was flung down a shaft on the second Death Star. However, just before his death he used the power of the dark side of the Force to transfer his consciousness into a cloned body, which is the version of the character that appears in The Rise of Skywalker. The "emperor" in The Force Awakens and The Last Jedi is a different character named Supreme Leader Snoke, who served a similar role as leader of the First Order, but was not the same person.